# How do I list all tables in a schema in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

How do i list all tables in a schema in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 256, accepted):

To see all tables in another schema, you need to have one or more of the following system privileges:

```
SELECT ANY DICTIONARY
(SELECT | INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE) ANY TABLE
```

or the big-hammer, the DBA role.

With any of those, you can select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OWNER, OBJECT_NAME 
  FROM DBA_OBJECTS
 WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
   AND OWNER = '[some other schema]'
```

Without those system privileges, you can only see tables you have been granted some level of access to, whether directly or through a role.

```
SELECT DISTINCT OWNER, OBJECT_NAME 
  FROM ALL_OBJECTS
 WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
   AND OWNER = '[some other schema]'
```

Lastly, you can always query the data dictionary for your own tables, as your rights to your tables cannot be revoked (as of 10g):

```
SELECT DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME 
  FROM USER_OBJECTS
 WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
```

Comment: the "most complete answer" apart from its use of `%_OBJECTS` instead of `%_TABLES`.

Comment: I remember in 9i that views would be listed in %_TABLES -- so, for example, trying to automate emptying a schema would end up with statements like DROP TABLE REALLY_A_VIEW CASCADE CONSTRAINTS throwing errors.  So you'd either have to remove the views with MINUS / NOT IN / NOT EXISTS or go agains %_OBJECTS.  Plus, going against %_OBJECTS leaves a tantalizing hint of what else might be in there!

Comment: There is absolutely no need for the `DISTINCT` in the query. `owner, object_name` is unique in `ALL_OBJECTS`

Comment: Those queries don't need distinct, that's true; however, `owner, object_name` is not unique by any means in dba_objects; Package Bodies and Packages both appear in that view, and Tables and Indexes are in different namespaces.

Comment: The last query won't work as is in XE 11.2. There is no 'owner' column in 'user_objects' it seems.

Answer (score 85):

```
SELECT table_name  from all_tables where owner = 'YOURSCHEMA';
```

Comment: This will only show *all* the tables in YOURSCHEMA if run by YOURSCHEMA or run by a user with the privileges mentioned by Adam Musch.  Otherwise it just shows the tables in YOURSCHEMA to which we have been granted privileges.

Answer (score 16):

You can query `USER_TABLES`

```
select TABLE_NAME from user_tables
```

Comment: That's all the tables in YOUR schema, not all the tables in A schema.  Also, the *_TABLES data dictionary views (DBA_TABLES, ALL_TABLES, USER_TABLES) include views.

Comment: replace "include views" with "can include views in seme versions of Oracle."

Comment: @Adam Musch Tested using Oracle 10g R2, it didn't return views.

Answer (score 6):

You can directly run the second query if you know the owner name.

--First you can select what all OWNERS there exist:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(owner) from SYS.ALL_TABLES;
```

--Then you can see the tables under by that owner:

```
SELECT table_name, owner from all_tables where owner like ('%XYZ%');
```

Answer (score 4):

If you logged in as Normal User without DBA permission you may uses the following command to see your own schema's  all tables and views.

```
select * from tab;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, replace ? with your schema name

```
select TABLE_NAME from  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA =?
  AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Comment: This is more database agnostic, and so I think this type of solution is better over all the alternatives.  I think INFORMATION_SCHEMA works on just about every major database I've seen.  Although some differ in what information you can get out, at least it's a consistent place to look.  However from doing a quick internet search, it appears Oracle is just about the only database to not support Information_Schema, even though it's part of the SQL-92 standard.

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from cat;
```

it will show all tables in your schema cat synonym of user_catalog

Answer (score 2):

If you are accessing Oracle with JDBC (Java) you can use [DatabaseMetadata](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) class. If you are accessing Oracle with ADO.NET you can use a similar approach.

If you are accessing Oracle with ODBC, you can use [SQLTables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711831(VS.85).aspx) function.

Otherwise, if you just need the information in SQLPlus or similar Oracle client, one of the queries already mentioned will do. For instance:

```
select TABLE_NAME from user_tables
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select TABLE_NAME from user_tables;
```

Above query will give you the names of all tables present in that user;

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from user_tables;
```

(showing all tables)

Answer (score 1):

SELECT  table_name, owner FROM all_tables where owner='schema_name' order by table_name

Answer (score 1):

Name of the table and rows counter for all tables under `OWNER` schema:

`SELECT table_name, num_rows counter from DBA_TABLES WHERE owner = 'OWNER'`

Answer (score 0):

Look at my [simple utility](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576534/) to show some info about db schema. It is based on: [Reverse Engineering a Data Model
Using the Oracle Data Dictionary](http://www.eveandersson.com/writing/data-model-reverse-engineering)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the size of the table as well, this will be handy:

`select SEGMENT_NAME, PARTITION_NAME, BYTES from user_segments where SEGMENT_TYPE='TABLE' order by 1`

Answer (score 0):

Show all tables under all schema each:

```sql
SELECT table_name, owner FROM all_tables;
```

Show all tables with specific schema:

```sql
SELECT table_name, owner FROM all_tables WHERE owner = 'SCHEMA_NAME';
```