# Get list of table names in different schema of an Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oracle: get list of all tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205736/oracle-get-list-of-all-tables)
>   [How do I list all tables in a schema in Oracle SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247310/how-do-i-list-all-tables-in-a-schema-in-oracle-sql)

I want to list all table in another schema.

```
connect hr/hr; 
select table_name from user_tables;
```

but I want to skip the "connect" command. I want to run query from another schema.
Is that possible to do?

Comment: [This looks like a dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247310/how-do-i-list-all-tables-in-a-schema-in-oracle-sql)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM ALL_TABLES 
WHERE OWNER='OTHER-SCHEMA'
```