# Display all views on oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, view, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there a way to display all the views currently set on an oracle database via sql developer?

Thanks.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247310/how-do-i-list-all-tables-in-a-schema-in-oracle-sql) may help.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

for all views (you need dba privileges for this query)

```
select view_name from dba_views
```

for all accessible views (accessible by logged user)

```
select view_name from all_views
```

for views owned by logged user

```
select view_name from user_views
```

Comment: You mean "We're sorry, the page you requested was not found." ? :)

Answer (score 17):

Open a new worksheet on the related instance `(Alt-F10)` and run the following query

```
SELECT view_name, owner
FROM sys.all_views 
ORDER BY owner, view_name
```

Comment: This is true only for your own views plus all views in other schemas which are granted to you either via role or directly. Depending on what has been granted, it may be just a subset of "all".
So, the question is, what does the author mean with "all views in database".

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * 
FROM DBA_OBJECTS  
WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'VIEW'
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Not every user has the privilege to select from DBA_views!