# In Rails console, how to see an Oracle view table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, console

In Rails console I can see the tables I have by issuing the command:

> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables

I have an Oracle view table, and it is not in this list. In the console I can do a find on the view and get results. I was hoping something like:

> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.views  # No such thing

but that would be a nope. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Lets open DB itself by running `rails dbconsole` (*short-cut alias: "db"*). Once you will get the db sessions, run the below query :

```
select view_name from all_views
```

Check this post [Display all views on oracle database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742717/display-all-views-on-oracle-database).

Comment: Yes, I can see the view using that. I am left scratching my head why I can run a query on a table and get results but on a view all I get is an SQLException: ORA-02019.