# sql statement to display all tables and views

Tags: sql, oracle

in homework, there is a question that wants me to display all objects from my account(wants to display all tables and views), but the problem is i didn't use Oracle to know how to do it due to corona virus.
thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display all views on oracle database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742717/display-all-views-on-oracle-database)

Comment: unfortunately no, my view name is test, so i should write "SELECT test FROM all_view" but i don't know what "all view" represent ? btw i'm running W3school website to try the solution you gave me, thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what the corona virus has to do with ability to access an oracle database.  Unless the db can only be accessed from on-campus and said campus is shut down.  In any event, since you don't know what "all_view" represents, it's high time you got familiar with the documentation.  Look  up 'all_views' in the Database Reference.  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/toc.htm

Comment: about Corona, yes that's true. And thanks for the reference, it helped me.

Comment: @EdStevens - these days I find myself confused by the meaning of phrases like "antivirus software". Could such software be used to fight corona virus? I view the op's reference in the same light.

Answer (score 0):

You want the `information_schema`. Since it's homework I'll stop there and leave it to you to explore the rest.

Comment: Well N.J. is using Oracle where there is no `information_schema`

Comment: as i said, i can't use Oracle due to Corona virus and other problems, the homework must be submit via MS Word and there i must write the statement.

Comment: @N.J You can download a free edition of Oracle to run on your own computer.

Comment: i did but i countered problem where i can't find the file of the oracle and when i download it again it says that the file is already in my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Objects that belong to your "account" - as you call it; it is "schema" in an Oracle database, i.e. "user" with all its objects - can be fetched from `user_objects`. Something like this:

I'm connected as user `scott`:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
```

What do I have?

```
SQL> desc user_objects
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 OBJECT_NAME                                        VARCHAR2(128)
 SUBOBJECT_NAME                                     VARCHAR2(30)
 OBJECT_ID                                          NUMBER
 DATA_OBJECT_ID                                     NUMBER
 OBJECT_TYPE                                        VARCHAR2(19)
 CREATED                                            DATE
 LAST_DDL_TIME                                      DATE
 TIMESTAMP                                          VARCHAR2(19)
 STATUS                                             VARCHAR2(7)
 TEMPORARY                                          VARCHAR2(1)
 GENERATED                                          VARCHAR2(1)
 SECONDARY                                          VARCHAR2(1)
 NAMESPACE                                          NUMBER
 EDITION_NAME                                       VARCHAR2(30)

SQL> select object_type, count(*)
  2  from user_objects
  3  group by object_type
  4  order by object_type;

OBJECT_TYPE           COUNT(*)
------------------- ----------
FUNCTION                     3
INDEX                        6
PROCEDURE                    4
SEQUENCE                     1
TABLE                       14
TRIGGER                      2
TYPE                         2
VIEW                         2

8 rows selected.
```

How to list all those objects?

```
SQL> select object_name, object_type
  2  from user_objects
  3  order by object_type, object_name;

OBJECT_NAME          OBJECT_TYPE
-------------------- -------------------
EMPLOYEE_FUNCTION    FUNCTION
F_SAL                FUNCTION
F_TEST               FUNCTION
PKA                  INDEX
PKB                  INDEX
PK_DEPT              INDEX
SYS_C0077379         INDEX
SYS_C0077382         INDEX
SYS_C0077385         INDEX
CHALLAN_TEST         PROCEDURE
P_CRV                PROCEDURE
P_MAIL               PROCEDURE
PRINT_TABLE          PROCEDURE
SEQA                 SEQUENCE
A                    TABLE
ALLOCATION           TABLE
B                    TABLE
BONUS                TABLE
DEPT                 TABLE
EMP                  TABLE
EMPLOYEES            TABLE
HSTT_SR_MST          TABLE
MASTER_TABLE         TABLE
NURSE                TABLE
ROOM                 TABLE
SALGRADE             TABLE
TEST                 TABLE
TEST_DEFVAL          TABLE
TRG_BI_DEF           TRIGGER
TRG_BI_TEST          TRIGGER
EMP_OBJ_TYPE         TYPE
EMP_TBL_TYPE         TYPE
VIEW_EXEC_DATA       VIEW
V_MASTER_TABLE       VIEW

34 rows selected.

SQL>
```

I guess that it answers your question.

---

Alternatively, if you had to display all objects you have access to, you'd query `all_objects` instead. Result is then very different:

```
SQL> select object_type, count(*)
  2  from all_objects
  3  group by object_type
  4  order by object_type;

OBJECT_TYPE           COUNT(*)
------------------- ----------
CONSUMER GROUP               2
DESTINATION                  2
DIRECTORY                    1
EDITION                      1
EVALUATION CONTEXT           1
FUNCTION                   217
INDEX                        6
INDEXTYPE                    9
JAVA CLASS               28751
JAVA RESOURCE              938
JOB CLASS                    2
OPERATOR                    55
PACKAGE                    553
PROCEDURE                   74
PROGRAM                     11
SCHEDULE                     3
SCHEDULER GROUP              4
SEQUENCE                    18
SYNONYM                  33399
TABLE                      119
TRIGGER                      2
TYPE                      1569
VIEW                      2257
WINDOW                       9
XML SCHEMA                  53

25 rows selected.

SQL>
```

I think you don't want to list all those tens of thousands of objects; that would be useless. Also, that view (`all_objects`) contains additional column name: `owner` which shows who owns those objects. Some of them are owned by you (and you already saw them in `user_objects`), while most of them don't. Include it into the query for more info.

---

Furthermore, if you were a DBA (or had appropriate privileges), you'd query `dba_objects` which contain objects within the whole database. It also contains the `owner` column.