# How do I get the number of rows in each table I have in my oracle database

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, rowcount

Can someone tell me how I can get the number of rows in each table in my oracle database? I have found several queries, but none of them worked because I am using oracle 7 and sql*plus 3.2 and basically all what I found didn't work on it. I just need something that would work on sql*plus 3.2.

Required:

Table Name          Rows

Table 1               0

Table 2               5

...

Is it possible to do it with something like a loop? Or what exactly should I do?

Comment: Why are you still using oracle 7? Is there something holding you back to upgrading to something more modern. Oracle 7 is from '92...

Comment: `SELECT table_name, num_rows from all_tables`  these are table statistics from which db engine uses to determine optimal execution paths, they are not 100% but usually close enough.  Also note, all_tables is limited to what you have access to see.  If you have no permissions to the table, you will not be able to see the table/record count in the results.

Comment: That's what I am trying to do. I am trying to update from oracle 7 to 10g or 11g, but there are many things that I need to figure out in the database before I can upgrade so that I don't mess things up, since it's a database of a company. I just need to know which tables that are useless and that I can drop. They have around 370 tables and I am sure they are only using around 50 or so tables, so I need to drop the rest and then I will react the new database on my own.

Comment: This "Might" be relevant... but 7 docs are painful to read and more painful to search.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247310/how-do-i-list-all-tables-in-a-schema-in-oracle-sql

Answer (score 2):

if `SELECT table_name, num_rows from all_tables` doesn't give you what you need.

You could use dynamic SQL and counts as Rahul selected.

Run the below to get results which dynamically build a union on all tables, then run the results as it's own query to get final results.

```
SELECT 'SELECT ' ||t.name || ' as tName, count(*) as Row_Cnt  
        FROM ' || t.name || ' UNION ALL '
FROM ALL_TABLES t
```

Just be sure to remove the last union statement on the last query.

Also note: if you don't have access to see the table, it will not come out in this list!

---Updated ------
So if all_tables doesn't exist none of this will work.  Since I don't have a oracle 7 instance handy... could you see if `SELECT * FROM dictionary` returns anything that might produce a list of all the tables? If you find a view or table object use it in place of all_tables above.

I'm reading the docs for oracle 7 now but finding little easily searchable.  thus a guess and check method may go faster.

Comment: Note that this question is about Oracle 7(!).  Did Oracle 7 even have optimizer statistics and the num_rows column?

Comment: I tried the num_rows column and it always gave me null answers. I tried to update it using the DBMS_STATS, but it said DBM_STATA must be declared first. Also I tried to a similar query to the one you wrote and it didn't work out as well.

SQL PLUS Code:

select 'select count(*) from '|| owner || '.' || table_name || ';' 
from dba_tables
where owner = 'xxxx'
order by table_name;

Comment: You're correct this is more of a > 7 answer.  I've not been able to find evidence of system tables existing in 7 yet.  Does 7 even have a dictionary to list the available system objects you could inquire upon `Select * from dictionary where table_name like '%TABLE%'`?

Comment: In Oracle 7, All_tables does exist, but the problem is with the num_rows not with the All_tables. It just returns null and when I tried to use the DBMS_STATS like I found online. It said that it must be declared first. I don't know about the from dictionary, but I don't think it would make a difference since my problem lies with either counting the rows or using the num_rows and both of them don't work.

Comment: I was going to have you look at dictionary to see if there was a different system table in 7 that contained the table listing.  If all tables is there and works, then it seems odd that the select to generate a select statement that you then ran wouldn't work.

Comment: Is it possible to make a loop and in each iteration to count the number of rows in each table?